# Bayesian equivalent of a 1-dimension table chi-squared test of independence analysis in R

Tags: r, bayesian, chi-squared

I have the following piece of R code (adapted from this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76342056/2950721)):

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate random data
n <- 490
V1 <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE)

# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(V1)

# Label the values: 1 = Low, 2 = High
expss::val_lab(df$V1) = expss::num_lab("1 Low
                                        2 High")

# Create a list of tables for each variable to count 1s, 2s, and NAs
count_results <- list(V1 = table(df$V1, useNA = "ifany"))

chisq.test(count_results$V1)
```

The result of the chi-squared test prints the following:

```
> chisq.test(count_results$V1)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  count_results$V1
X-squared = 0.2, df = 2, p-value = 0.9048
```

However, when I try with the `BayesFactor`'s `contingencyTableBF()` function I get an error:

```
> BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF(count_results$V1, sampleType = "indepMulti")
Error in BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF(count_results$V1, sampleType = "indepMulti") : 
  Argument fixedMargin ('rows' or 'cols') required with independent multinomial sampling plan.
```

My questions:

1. Can `BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF()` be used in such a case?
2. If yes, given the example above, what would be the correct syntax?
3. If not, given the example above, what function would allow me to get the Bayesian equivalent of a 1-dimension table chi-squared analysis?

Comment: The answer to question 1 is no.  From the help file, the input table `x` says: " 
an m by n matrix of counts (integers m,n > 1)", so it has to have more than 1 row and more than 1 column.  The second question is thus moot and the third question would probably get closed because you're asking for advice on packages or tools, which is outside the scope of SO.  Perhaps asking the third question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) might work.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong. Thanks for your answer. Will follow advice and ask on CrossValidated.