# Bayesian chi-squared goodness of fit test analysis (1-dimension table) in R

Tags: r, bayesian, goodness-of-fit

I have the following piece of R code (adapted from this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76342056/2950721)):

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate random data
n <- 490
V1 <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE)

# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(V1)

# Label the values: 1 = Low, 2 = High
expss::val_lab(df$V1) = expss::num_lab("1 Low
                                        2 High")

# Create a list of tables for each variable to count 1s, 2s, and NAs
count_results <- list(V1 = table(df$V1, useNA = "ifany"))

chisq.test(count_results$V1)
```

The result of the chi-squared test prints the following:

```
> chisq.test(count_results$V1)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  count_results$V1
X-squared = 0.2, df = 2, p-value = 0.9048
```

However, when I try with the `BayesFactor`'s `contingencyTableBF()` function I get an error:

```
> BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF(count_results$V1, sampleType = "indepMulti")
Error in BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF(count_results$V1, sampleType = "indepMulti") : 
  Argument fixedMargin ('rows' or 'cols') required with independent multinomial sampling plan.
```

According to a comment to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77128545/2950721), `BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF()` "has to have more than 1 row and more than 1 column". Because the poster mentions: "From the help file, the input table x says: 'an m by n matrix of counts (integers m,n > 1)', so it has to have more than 1 row and more than 1 column". Therefore, `BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF()` cannot work with what I'm looking for.

Consequently, my questions are:

1. Given the example above, what function would allow me to get the Bayesian equivalent of a chi-square goodness of fit in R (i.e., a 1-dimension table)?
2. Can you please put in practice the function with the code posted above so it produces a BF result?

---

P.S.: As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77128545/2950721), I asked the question in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), however, from there I have been sent back here as my query has more to do with a programmation question than a theoretical one.