# Frequency count and all combination analysis in R?

Tags: r, combinations, frequency

The following code generates data ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77152229/2950721)):

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate random data
n <- 490
PTSD <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE) #class(PTSD) = "numeric"
ANX <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE) #class(ANX) = "numeric"
DEP <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE) #class(DEP) = "numeric"

# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(PTSD, ANX, DEP) #class(df) = "data.frame"

# Label the values: 1 = Low, 2 = High
expss::val_lab(df$PTSD) = expss::num_lab("1 Low
                                        2 High")
expss::val_lab(df$ANX) = expss::num_lab("1 Low
                                        2 High")
expss::val_lab(df$DEP) = expss::num_lab("1 Low
                                        2 High")

# Create a list of tables for each variable to count 1s, 2s, and NAs
count_results <- list(
  PTSD = table(df$PTSD, useNA = "ifany"),
  ANX = table(df$ANX, useNA = "ifany"),
  DEP = table(df$DEP, useNA = "ifany")
)
```

This portion of the code does some frequency count and summarises data:

```
# Combine the count tables into a single table
count_table <- do.call(rbind, count_results)

# Initialize empty vectors to store results
variable_names <- character()
sample_sizes <- numeric()

# Loop through the test results and extract relevant information
for (variable_name in names(count_results)) {
  sample_sizes <- c(sample_sizes, sum(count_results[[variable_name]]))
  variable_names <- c(variable_names, variable_name)
}

# Create summary data frame
summary_df <- data.frame(
  Variable = variable_names,
  N = sample_sizes
)

# Combine the count table and chi-squared summary table by columns
final_result <- cbind(count_table, summary_df)

# Remove Variable column in the middle of the table
final_result <- subset(final_result, select = -c(Variable))
```

This portion of the code does what I call "combination analysis" (it is [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77171479/2950721) of the above mentioned SO thread):

```
t3 <- c("PTSD","ANX","DEP")

combs <- map(seq_along(t3),\(n)combn(t3,n,simplify = FALSE)) |> flatten()

filts <- parse_exprs(map_chr(combs,\(x)paste0(x ,'== 2',collapse=' & ')))
filtsnames <- parse_exprs(map_chr(combs,\(x)paste0(x ,collapse=' + ')))
names(filts) <- filtsnames

out2 <- map_int(filts,\(x){
  df %>%
    mutate(id = row_number())%>%
    filter(!!(x))%>%
    summarise(
      n = n())
} |> pull(n)
)

enframe(out2)
```

The last command generates this (which is what was requested by the author of the question):

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  name             value
  <chr>            <int>
1 PTSD               167
2 ANX                156
3 DEP                156
4 PTSD + ANX          56
5 PTSD + DEP          52
6 ANX + DEP           51
7 PTSD + ANX + DEP    23
```

However, when looking into it, the number of combinations is higher than that, namely (with corrected table generated in MS Excel, function `COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, ...)`:

```
Combination                     n
---------------------------------
PTSD High                     167
PTSD High, ANX Low             61
PTSD High, DEP Low             58
PTSD High, ANX High            56
PTSD High, DEP High            52
PTSD High, ANX Low, DEP Low    24
PTSD High, ANX High, DEP Low   14
PTSD High, ANX Low, DEP High   16
PTSD High, ANX High, DEP High  23
    
ANX High                      156
ANX High, PTSD Low             50
ANX High, DEP Low              46
ANX High, DEP High             51
ANX High, PTSD Low, DEP Low    19
ANX High, PTSD Low, DEP High   14
    
DEP High                      156
DEP High, PTSD Low             57
DEP High, ANX Low              52
DEP High, PTSD Low, ANX Low    17
```

My question:

- Assuming there are no missing combinations in the table above, what would be the R code in order to obtain all the combinations and the pertaining frequencies?

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[,.(n = .N), names(df)]` will get the counts of unique combinations. The rest would be text manipulation.

Comment: @jblood94. Thanks for your comment. However, your solution does not address what I need: it inserts the NAs that blur the results, same with the 1s.

Comment: @JosephWood. Unfortunately not. If you look carefully, I refer to that post in my question. The answers to the post to which you refer only partially answer my query. I would like a much more thorough solution, but which does not include NAs and 1s in the counts (see comment made by jblood94).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you explain how you get the values in the final table? For example, why does "PTSD High" get a value of 51?

Comment: @jblood94. You are totally right. I pasted the data of another table. My apologies. The table has been corrected and I added how I obtained the numbers: I exported the data frame to CSV and did the calculations one by one with the `COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, ...)` in MS Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `model.matrix` with interaction effects you can get the combinations you want from `df`:

First we set the missing in `df` to zero and set the columns to be factors:

```
> df[is.na(df)] <- 0
> df <- lapply(df, factor) |> as.data.frame()
```

Then find the model matrix, sum the columns:

```
> all_combs <- model.matrix(~PTSD*ANX*DEP , df) |> colSums()
```

Finally I think you only keep the elements with at least one 'high' value (check this is really what you want to do):

```
> all_combs[grepl("High",names(all_combs))] |> cbind()

                          [,1]
PTSDHigh                  167
ANXHigh                   156
DEPHigh                   156
PTSDHigh:ANXLow            61
PTSDLow:ANXHigh            50
PTSDHigh:ANXHigh           56
PTSDHigh:DEPLow            58
PTSDLow:DEPHigh            57
PTSDHigh:DEPHigh           52
ANXHigh:DEPLow             46
ANXLow:DEPHigh             52
ANXHigh:DEPHigh            51
PTSDHigh:ANXLow:DEPLow     24
PTSDLow:ANXHigh:DEPLow     19
PTSDHigh:ANXHigh:DEPLow    14
PTSDLow:ANXLow:DEPHigh     17
PTSDHigh:ANXLow:DEPHigh    16
PTSDLow:ANXHigh:DEPHigh    14
PTSDHigh:ANXHigh:DEPHigh   23
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your last command misses a closing parenthesis after `all_combs)`. I tried to correct your post, however I get the message `Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?`. Would you mind correcting? And YES, that is exactly what I was looking for! :-D

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. I'm not going to mess with `expss`:

```
set.seed(123)

# Generate random data
n <- 490
PTSD <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE) #class(PTSD) = "numeric"
ANX <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE) #class(ANX) = "numeric"
DEP <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE) #class(DEP) = "numeric"

# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(PTSD, ANX, DEP) #class(df) = "data.frame"
```

Here is a general solution. First, create a list of vectors--one vector for each column. Each vector goes from `0` to the number of levels in that column. Then, use a subset of `expand.grid` for the set of combinations to count.

```
lvls <- rep(list(0:2), 3) # 2 = High, 1 = Low, 0 = Any value
mCombos <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lvls))
mCombos <- mCombos[matrixStats::rowMaxs(as.matrix(mCombos)) == 2,]
```

Get `df` as a matrix and replace `NA` values with `0`.

```
m <- as.matrix(df)
m[is.na(m)] <- 0L
```

For a combination represented by a row of `mCombos`, a row of `m` will be counted if the sum of the product of the two rows is equal to the sum of the squared elements of the combination from `mCombos`. For example, for the combination `c(2, 0, 1)` (PTSD High, DEP Low), we would count the 11th row of `m` (`c(2, 2, 1)`) because `2*2 + 0*2 + 1*1 = 2^2 + 0^2 + 1^2`. We can use `tcrossprod` to do the full set of comparisons:

```
setNames(
  cbind(
    as.data.frame(mCombos),
    rowSums(tcrossprod(mCombos, m) == rowSums(mCombos^2))
  ),
  c(names(df), "n")
)
#>    PTSD ANX DEP   n
#> 1     2   0   0 167
#> 2     2   1   0  61
#> 3     0   2   0 156
#> 4     1   2   0  50
#> 5     2   2   0  56
#> 6     2   0   1  58
#> 7     2   1   1  70
#> 8     0   2   1  46
#> 9     1   2   1  68
#> 10    2   2   1  14
#> 11    0   0   2 156
#> 12    1   0   2  57
#> 13    2   0   2  52
#> 14    0   1   2  52
#> 15    1   1   2  58
#> 16    2   1   2  16
#> 17    0   2   2  51
#> 18    1   2   2  14
#> 19    2   2   2  23
```